# tx_news / eventnews: Setting PAGE_TSCONFIG_IDLIST for organizer and location

Tags: typo3, tsconfig, tx-news

For [tx_news](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/news) I can define (via Page TSconfig) e.g. a list of PIDs from where to select the available system categories for a news record. The tsConfig would look like this:

```
TCEFORM.tx_news_domain_model_news.categories.PAGE_TSCONFIG_IDLIST = 12345,12346,12347
```

Now my Question: Is something like this possible for the organizer and location records coming with tx_news based [eventnews](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/eventnews)? So the organizer and location items available on a eventnews record will be filtered by their PID? I tried sth. like this:

```
TCEFORM.tx_news_domain_model_news.organizer.PAGE_TSCONFIG_IDLIST = 12345
TCEFORM.tx_news_domain_model_news.location.PAGE_TSCONFIG_IDLIST = 12345
```

But it didn´t work, so I guess it is not implemented yet.
Does anybody know another way to get this done, a workaround or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must modify the TCA of the `tx_news_domain_model_news.organizer` and `tx_news_domain_model_news.location` to archive this.

As you can see [here](https://github.com/georgringer/eventnews/blob/master/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tx_news_domain_model_news.php#L45) and [here](https://github.com/georgringer/eventnews/blob/master/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tx_news_domain_model_news.php#L60) there is no marker like `###PAGE_TSCONFIG_IDLIST###` as referenced [here](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/7.6/Reference/Columns/Select/Index.html#foreign-table-where).

You should make it like this:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_news_domain_model_news']['columns']['organizer']['config']['foreign_table_where'] = ' AND pid IN (###PAGE_TSCONFIG_IDLIST###) ORDER BY tx_eventnews_domain_model_organizer.title';
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_news_domain_model_news']['columns']['location']['config']['foreign_table_where'] = ' AND pid IN (###PAGE_TSCONFIG_IDLIST###) ORDER BY tx_eventnews_domain_model_location.title';
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I put it in my template extensions ext_tables.php like this
`$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_news_domain_model_news']['columns']['organizer']['config']['foreign_table_where'] = ' AND tx_eventnews_domain_model_organizer.pid IN (###PAGE_TSCONFIG_IDLIST###) ORDER BY tx_eventnews_domain_model_organizer.title';`
(added the table name to WHERE part to prevent ambiguous SELECT)

Comment: I recommend to put this in your template extension under the directory "Configuration/TCA/Override/" in the file "tx_news_domain_model_news.php".